# Exported XLS file either opens with wrong encoding, or with all data in one column

Tags: javascript, html, excel, csv

I have a function written in JS that generates an XLS file to download from an HTML table. Everything is working fine, except that all the values in a row appear in a single column if the XLS file is opened directly. However, if I leave out BOM at the charset declaration, then the values appear in seperate columns but it messes up the encoding with the special characters.

Here is the code I use:

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

        // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
        // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '"\t"',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();

                return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/ms-excel;charset=utf-8,\ufeff' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'
    });
}

// This must be a hyperlink
$(".excelExport").on('click', function (event) {
    // CSV
    $(".timeStampUt").show();
    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#xlsData'), 'oszido-<?php echo $now_date1; ?>-<?php echo $now_time1; ?>.xls']);  //Change name of excel as per your need
    $(".timeStampUt").hide();

    if($(this).hasClass("utExcelExport")) {
        changeValue('ClosureOfAid', 'no', 'utExcelExport-retired-isNotNull');
    }
    // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
    // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
});
```

If I try to open it from Data>From Text and open the XLS from there, everything works fine. This is fine for me, however my client expects it to work directly by opening the file. How can I deal with this?

Comment: You are confusing XLS and CSV here.  You are generating CSV data but keep calling it XLS and giving it an `application/ms-excel` MIME type. CSV usually gets `text/csv` as MIME type.